# attributes not saving with file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This is probably easy, but I can not seam to figure it out - maybe it's late. I have a simple program that takes the text from an `NSTextView` and saves it as `rtf`. Saving the text itself works great, I just can not figure out how to get the attributes to tag along.

Code:

```
 NSAttributedString *saveString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                    initWithString:[textView string]];

 NSData *writeResults = [saveString 
                           RTFFromRange:NSMakeRange:(0, [saveString length])
                           doumentAttributes:?? ];

 [writeResults writeToURL:[panel URL] atomically: YES];
```

I know I need an `NSDictionary` for the `documentAttributes`, so how do I get that from the view?

What am I missing?

Comment: There are no attributes given you don't set any in the attributed string (not even sure what that `string` method is that you're calling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are asking the textView for its string property. You need to ask it for its attributedString property:

```
NSAttributedString *saveString = textView.attributedString;
```

You can get the attributes from an attributed string like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *allAttributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[saveString enumerateAttribuesInRange:NSMakeRange(0,saveString.length) options:NSAttributedStringEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(NSDictionary *attrs, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
    [allAttrubutes addEntriesFromDictionary:attrs];
}];
NSData *writeResults = [saveString.string RTFFromRange:NSMakeRange(0,saveString.length) documentAttributes:allAttributes];
```

I have used this method to get attributes many times however I have never saved to RTF so I don't know exactly how this will turn out. All the attributes will be in the dictionary however.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. Only change to your code for it to work is on the NSData line. NSData *writeResults = [saveString RTFFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, saveString.length) documentAttributes:allAttributes];